# failed how to apply Media queries to my style sheet

Tags: css, media

I'm not familiar with media queries from last 2 days I try a lot and search for several time but still I'm failed to add queries to my style sheet...

I just want to apply media queries into my css for all devices. any one can help me set the proper width and height for all div,table.

here's code

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 979px) {
html ,body{ 
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   /* overflow-x: hidden;*/ 
text-align: right;  direction: rtl;
}

body {
  background:#77d5fb;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 11px; 
 font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 opacity: .98;

}

table.body {
 width: 950px;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top:70px;
 border-radius: 6px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
   -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #fff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #fff;
min-height:100%;
}

.container{
width:100%;
background:#fff;
min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom:105px;

}

#footer{
background:#eee;
      left:0px;
      right:0px;
      bottom:0px;
      width:100%;
      height:171px;
   position:absolute;   
  }   
  

        #Layer1 {
 position:absolute;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 z-index:1;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
background: #fff;
   text-align: right;  direction: rtl;
} 
    
div.content {
 width: 950px; 
 padding: 10px 0px 20px 0px; 
 text-align: left; 
 margin-left: auto; 
 margin-right: auto;
 min-height:100%;

}}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="Layer1">Top Nav</div>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='body' align='center'>
<tr>
    <td><div class='content'>Content here</div></td></tr></table><div id='footer'>Footer</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're after, but for obtaining the `responsive` design, then you should use `%` rather than fixed widths, ie - `px`.

If this isn't what you're after, please create a `fiddle`.

A side note - setting `opacity` on the body will affect all the elements that sit on top of it. It's better to use `rgba` on the `background` rather than setting `opacity`.

```
body {
  /* background:#77d5fb; 
  opacity: .98;*/
  background-color: rgba(119,213,251, .98);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;  
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

}

You should remove the `950px`, since that will go outside the container if the width of the `body` is less than `950px`. Set these to `percentages` rather than fixed widths. Also there's no point in using `table` if you're not using them for their purpose. Use `floats` with `%` width values (if needed), rather than `table`.

```
table.body {
  width: 90%;  /* or 100%, depending on what you're after */
  /* other css styles */
}


div.content {
    width: 90%;  /* or 100%, depending on what you're after */
    /* other css styles */
}
```

You start by doing mobile first, like so:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 560px) {
    // styles here
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    // styles for that size here
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
   // desktops
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
   // large desktops
}
```

If you want `orientation`, then you need to do:

```
@media (min-device-width: XXXpx) and (max-device-width: XXXpx) and (orientation:portrait) 
*/ or orientation:landscape */ {
     // styles
}
```

***Important***

You need this in your header before ANY `media` queries will work

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
```

Comment: yes I'm trying to design responsive page with above css code, but don't know how to fix the width and height for devices. which code I should remove and which code I should add to, get page for responsive design ;)

Comment: above css code is the original code of style design for browser I just want the code add inside media queries code 'media {...}'... I also add meta tag in head but still not sure which code I should remove from my original css code and what code should I add that work perfect for all added devices